failed to add a leaflet ruler plugin
i always get : js: Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
Add Leaflet-Ruler plugin
    m.get_root().header.add_child(folium.CssLink("https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"))
    m.get_root().header.add_child(folium.CssLink("https://cdn.rawgit.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler/master/src/leaflet-ruler.css"))
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.JavascriptLink("https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"))
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.JavascriptLink("https://cdn.rawgit.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler/master/src/leaflet-ruler.js"))
    my_js = '''
    L.control.ruler().addTo(map);
    '''
    m.get_root().script.add_child(folium.Element(my_js))

i trired to add this plugin to a folium map in python but i always get error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

it is wrong to try to add the plugin directly to my code but it' better to add the plugin to the folium library plugins so i take one of the simple plugins .py file in the folder and edited it then i put it in the plugins folder inside folium and editted the init.py so i can call the Ruler function to add the plugin . Hans Then from folium community in github guided me to do this , many thanks to him
from branca.element import MacroElement
from jinja2 import Template

from folium.elements import JSCSSMixin
from folium.utilities import parse_options


class Ruler(JSCSSMixin, MacroElement):
    """
    Adds a ruler button to your map to measure bearing and distance.

    See https://https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler for more information.
    """

    _template = Template(
        """
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            L.control.ruler(
                {{ this.options|tojson }}
            ).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
        {% endmacro %}
        """
    )  # noqa

    default_js = [
        (
            "Control.Ruler.js",
            "https://cdn.rawgit.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler/master/src/leaflet-ruler.js",
        )
    ]
    default_css = [
        (
            "Control.Ruler.css",
            "https://cdn.rawgit.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler/master/src/leaflet-ruler.css",
        )
    ]

    def __init__(self, options=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.options = options or {
            "position": "topright",
            "lengthUnit": {
                "factor": 0.539956803,  # from km to nm
                "display": "nm",
                "decimal": 2,
                "label": 'Distance:',
            },
        }

